# Using globals() to augment django settings

Tags: python, django

It seems to be relatively normal in the Django world to import a local environment settings override file at the end of `settings.py`, something like:

```
from settings_local.py import *
```

This has a couple of issues, most notably for me being that you cannot inspect or modify base settings, only override them - which leads to some painful duplication and headaches over time.

Instead, is there anything wrong with importing an init function from a local file and injecting the output of `globals()` to allow that local file to read and modify the settings a bit more intelligently?

**settings.py:**

```
from settings_local.py import init
init( globals() )
```

**settings_local.py:**

```
def init( config ):
    config['INSTALLED_APPS'].append( 'some.app' )
```

This seems to address a number of the concerns related to using `import *`, but I'd like to know if this is a bad idea for a reason I am not yet aware of.

Comment: What's going to happen if multiple user access that resource at the same time?

Comment: You mean like using a [json file](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/942/settings/8734/hiding-secret-data-using-a-json-file#t=201701131912361366116) to store settings?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more common and readable way to handle this is to have multiple settings files, where you put all the common settings in one module and import that at the beginning of the environment-specific settings files:

```
settings
    __init__.py
    base.py
    development.py
    staging.py
    production.py
```

This allows you the mutations you are referring to:

```
# base.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'foo',
    'bar'
]

# development.py
from .base import *

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'debug_toolbar'
]
```

Then you run your app locally with `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.development`

Comment: Yea, I've come across this too. I like how it results in the environment overrides end up in the same syntax as the base settings file - unlike in my proposed approach.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the main point. Keep your settings structure simple, without too much coding logic. The readability aspect becomes even more pressing when you run multiple servers with different tasks (and thus different settings) for the same application. Then, you have multiple such `xx_settings` packages where all the modules import from the appropriate level module of the `settings` package as well as from their own `base.py`